# Separate processes for Dockerfile for dev and prod?

Tags: django, docker, nginx, docker-compose, gunicorn

I have a project with the following structure.

```
ProjectName/
├── Dockerfile
├── api/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   └── manage.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── frontend/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── build/
│   └── src/
└── manifests/
    ├── development.yml
    └── production.yml
```

docker-compose.yml has a database image that's common between both environments, and the dev.yml and prod.yml have similar but slightly different images for production and dev.

Example:  The api dev uses django and just runs `python manage.py runserver`, but in prod it will run `gunicorn api.wsgi`.

And the frontend runs `npm start` but in prod I want it to be based off a different image.  Currently the dockerfile only works with one or the other, since the `npm` command is only found when I use `FROM node` and the `nginx` command only shows up when I use `FROM kyma/docker-nginx`.

**So how can I separate these out when in different environments?**

./frontend/Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /app/frontend
COPY package.json /app/frontend

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]

# Only run this bit in production environment, and not anything above this line.
#FROM kyma/docker-nginx
#COPY build/ /var/www
#CMD 'nginx'
```

./api/Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.5

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app/api
COPY requirements.txt /app/api
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

# Run this command in dev
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
# Run this command in prod
#CMD ["gunicorn", "api.wsgi", "-b 0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

./docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
  - "5432:5432"

volumes:
  node-modules:
```

./manifests/production.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  gunicorn:
    build: ./api
    command: ["gunicorn", "api.wsgi", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  nginx:
    build: ./frontend
    command: ["nginx"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/frontend
      - ./frontend:/var/www
      - node-modules:/app/frontend/node_modules
    ports:
      - "80:80"

volumes:
  node-modules:
```

./manifests/development.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  django:
    build: ./api
    command: ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./api:/app/api
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    command: ["npm", "start"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./frontend:/app/frontend
      - node-modules:/app/frontend/node_modules
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

volumes:
  node-modules:
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have as an ENTRYPOINT a script running one or the other command depending of an environment variable that you can set at run time:

```
docker run -e env=DEV
# or
docker run -e env=PROD
```

You can set that same [environment variable in a docker compose file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

Comment: Ok so I add 

        environment:
          - DEV (or PROD)

To all the images.  How do I use it in my Dockerfile though?  Do I just have 2 sections, with `ENTRYPOINT "DEV"` at the top?

Comment: @cclloyd your dockerfile would call one unique script which, depending on the environment variable value, would call the right command.

Comment: But then how do I have the containers be based off different bases?  (Not too familiar with how dockerfiles work yet)

Comment: @cclloyd You would need to build an image able to do both, with both framework installed.